# How to manually set a controller variable from a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nokogiri

I'm trying to enter a URL from the view and pass it into my controller and set it equal to a variable. I'm trying it like this currently but it just keeps returning nil.

This is Controller/posts:

```
def run
  url = params[:url_toget]
  puts  url
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  post = Post.create do |post|
    post.body = doc.at_css("body")
    post.url_toget = url
   end
end
```

This is Views posts:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%=text_field :url_toget, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Recipe URL" %>
</div>

<%= link_to "Rake", posts_run_path %>
```

How can I input a URL and have it pass to equal that variable?

Comment: Instance variables are only passed from controller=> view, not vice versa. You need to pass the info as a parameter in the form, and read it from the controller with `params`. It looks like your `link_to` is not passing the info from the text_field. Read up on rails forms for some help.

Comment: Are you using Nokogiri to parse your own HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly set variables from the view to the controller but you can post the request from the view.

Like:

```
<%= form_tag( '/run' ) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'my_url' %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller run action access the parameter: `p params[:my_url]`

Remember to enable the POST method for the run action in routes: `post 'run', to: 'your_controller#run'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to name a form based on the Controller Action.
The way I did it was to do the following:

This is in HAML

```
%h2 #{params[:action].capitalize} Branch
```

If you wanted to do it in HTML you would do the following:

```
<h2>#{params[:action].capitalize} Branch</h2>
```

This resulted in the form being named Edit Branch when I was editing and New Branch when I was using the NEW action etc.

I hope this helps someone else.

Scott